# minio - get files from Minio by date using Minio .NET SDK

Tags: c#, minio

I'm trying to create an application using Minio + Minio .NET SDK that'll retrieve all files uploaded in the past 5 minutes only, however, it seems like the only way is browse all the files and get their file timestamp which is quite inefficient. Has anyone had any luck using a date parameter with their SDK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked with one of the project maintainers, as of now, it's not possible to do so using their SDK (https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/17470) .

However , an alternative could be using minio console commands

`mc find --newer-than 5m`